# Selenium IEDriverServer not sending keys when using RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, grid

So I have a test case set up which works perfectly fine using Testng and running the IEDriverServer locally. But when running the test case using Grid 2 the following command doesn't appear to work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[3]")).sendKeys(logNum);
```

There are no errors and the output from the node states that it had completed, but no text appears in the edit box. I checked running the test through a debugger and the "logNum" variable does have a value

I can not fathom why its not working

I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar running the Hub and Node on the same machine

Comment: Could be almost anything. Is the page slower on the Grid? Do you need to wait longer? Is it possible your XPath is picking up the wrong element?

Comment: No I am selecting the correct element and there are no errors when running via the Grid. Works fine locally.

Comment: What value and data type is your logNum variable?

Comment: The value is a 4 character random digit and its String type. This code has no issues with Firefox local or remote.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by removing

```
capability.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
```

from my initiation of the driver.

Comment: This will work until eventually you need to do something that require native events. Good luck!

Comment: And that's just the problem :-\

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same problem. I used JavascriptExecutor to set the value of the element.

```
public static void useJSSendKeys(String value,WebElement element){
    JavascriptExecutor myExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    myExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+value+"';", element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

good to know that your issue is resolved on making capability.setCapability("nativeEvents", false); but it may create problem when you try to perform native events. so if you not tried, please try performing click before sendkeys. it helps me some times and also providing Thread.sleep(3000) in java also helps me in some situations. please try these if not.

Thank You,
Murali